# How to fix C++ gcc compile warning for padding of struct

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, suppress-warnings

I have the following innocuous looking code:

```
void myFunc(){
    struct stance {
        long double interval;
        QString name;
    };
    // [...]
}
```

When I build this using standard version of gcc on Ubuntu 18.04 I get a warning like this:

> MySource.cpp:12: warning: padding size of 'stance' with 8 bytes to
>   alignment boundary (-wpadded)

I know that this warning shows up because the compiler needs to adjust the padding for my struct to something that I might not have expected and is kind enough to warn me as the user about this.

However, I am trying to have a warning-free build and so the question is, **how can I make it explicit in my code in a standard compliant way that the compiler does not need to issue this warning?**

So to be clear, I **don't want to suppress warnings** in my build script, nor using #pragma or similar either. I want to **change the code** of this struct so that my alignment expectations are explicit and match whatever the compiler wants to do hence not needing the warning to be displayed.

Comment: Strange. My GCC doesn't have the warning option `-wpadding`. What version is yours?

Comment: Sorry it is -wpadded, will update Q

Comment: You’re making a lot of unnecessary work for yourself. Unless object sizes and alignments are critical to your application this just isn’t important.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I disagree. Unecessary warnings in the build will hide real warnings. Striving for a warning free build is a well known best practice that is worth striving for. Further, having to add complexity to the build process through obscure compiler flags or adding complexity to the code itself by amending it with  a bunch of less portable and/or needlessly obscure meta statements sill severely degrade the purity of the project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just disable the warning (or - well, don't enable it, I don't know of any warning set like `-Wall` or `-Wextra` that includes it). `-Wpadded` is not meant to be always enabled, unless you want to always manually specify the necessary padding explicitly.

> -Wpadded
>
> Warn if padding is included in a structure, either to align an element of the structure or to align the whole structure. *Sometimes* when this happens it is possible to rearrange the fields of the structure to reduce the padding and so make the structure smaller.

(emphasis added)

This is one case where it's not possible. `long double` is 10 bytes, and it requires 16 bytes alignment (4 on x86 Linux); `QString` is effectively a pointer, so it needs 8 bytes alignment (4 on 32 bit Linux). You can swap them however you want, but if you want to keep natural alignment (and thus best performance) you'll either get 6 + 8 bytes of padding or 8 + 6 bytes of padding.

In general, adding padding is not a problem, happens all the time and there are cases such as this when it's unavoidable. The general rule to keep it at a minimum is to place elements in order of decreasing alignment requirements, but again, it cannot always be avoided.

As mentioned above, the only alternative (keeping good alignment) is making the padding explicit, but it doesn't make much sense (unless you are designing a file format or something and you want to make everything explicit, but in that case you wouldn't use a `QString` and would pack to 1 byte).

```
struct stance {
    long double interval;
    char unused0[6];
    QString name;
    char unused1[8];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using explicit padding:

```cpp
    #include <cstdint>

    #define EXPLICIT_PADDING_BITS(N) uint8_t : N;

    struct stance {
        long double interval;
        QString name;
        EXPLICIT_PADDING_BITS(8)
    };
```

Without the padding, you'll trip `-Wpadded` in GCC and Clang (as you saw), and warning `C4324` in MSVC.

From the standard ([§14.9.2, part 2, ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf#subsection.11.4.9)):

> A declaration for a bit-field that omits the identifier declares an
> unnamed bit-field. Unnamed bit-fields are not members and cannot be
> initialized. An unnamed bit-field shall not be declared with a
> cv-qualified type. [Note: An unnamed bit-field is useful for padding
> to conform to externally-imposed layouts. — end note] As a special
> case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero specifies alignment of
> the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary. Only when declaring
> an unnamed bit-field may the width be zero.

If you want to pad more than 8 bits, you could use an unnamed `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, or `uint64_t` (but keep in mind that will make the minimum padding of the structure at least 2, 4, and 8 bytes respectively).

If you want to pad more than 8 bytes, you can't use an unnamed bit-field. You'll need to write something like this:

```cpp
    #include <cstdint>

    // We need to add the second "CONCATENATE_" macro to ensure that the
    // special "__COUNTER__" macro is expanded before it's concatenated
    // to "PADDING_MACRO_".
    #define CONCATENATE_(a,b) a##b
    #define CONCATENATE(a,b) CONCATENATE_(a,b)
    #define EXPLICIT_PADDING_BYTES(N) uint8_t CONCATENATE(PADDING_MACRO_, __COUNTER__)[N];

    // Suppose we want to avoid false-sharing, so we make sure that
    // our structure occupies its own entire 64-byte cache line:
    struct alignas(64) example {
        uint64_t atomic_counter;
        EXPLICIT_PADDING_BYTES(56);
    };
```

Comment: This is really interesting, but I don't understand it; can you try making this more clear?

Comment: @FluffyRibbit I've rewritten the answer for clarity

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the code of this struct so that my alignment expectations are explicit

It looks like you want the [`alignof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) and use it with [`alignas` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas). So you need at least C++11 and you might want [`std::alignment_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/alignment_of)

Comment: How would I go about using those?

Comment: Although this makes it explicit, it does not clobber the warning for gcc.